# Django loading static files?

Tags: python, html, django

Django is not loading my static files. However it is loading my templates which are in the static folder. Also chrome is not seeing the static files either I'm not even getting a 404 error and yes they are linked in the html...but they are not showing up in the network panel

Heres my settings.py file

```
    STATIC_ROOT = ''

    STATIC_URL = '/static/'

    STATICFILES_DIRS =(
         os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
     )
```

Here's my html

```
    <head>
        <title>MySite | Home</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' src='css/normalize.css'>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Questrial|Josefin+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src='css/main.css'>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    </head>
```

Sorry I know this question has been asked multiple times and i've tried all those solutions with no luck. I've spent 2 days trying to figure this out

Comment: Why would your templates be in the static folder?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Is that bad? That's how a tutorial I watched was doing it, where would be a better place for them?

Comment: I hardly know how to respond to that. Those are completely different things. I highly doubt any decent tutorial would do that. In any case, you haven't given nearly enough information to answer the question. Are you running in development? Is DEBUG True or False? Why is your `STATIC_ROOT` empty? Have you run `manage.py collectstatic`? What is the value of your TEMPLATE_DIRS? Why are you using relative paths to point to your CSS files in your template?

Comment: @Groovietunes I mean absolutely no offense by this at all, but Daniel, I laughed so hard at the first sentence of your comment; that made my day.

Comment: @Groovietunes you definitely don't want to put your Django templates inside of your static directory, unless of course they're templates that you're leveraging with say, underscore for example.

Comment: @DanielRoseman DEBUG is set to true. I have just started this project, I'm in Development. STATIC_ROOT is empty because it was solution that I found on here that did not work for me. I have previously run collect static but I was sure that the STATIC_ROOT and collect static were only for deployment. I have swapped between src and href in the template along with changing the path with no luck. For TEMPLATE the DIRS are set to os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/templates')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The approach I take with static files is basically what's outlined in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/staticfiles/).

In local development, Django will serve static files automatically from the directory specified in `STATIC_ROOT` as long as `django.contrib.staticfiles` is in your `INSTALLED_APPS` and `DEBUG = True`

My project structure typically looks like this:

```
my_project/
    some_app/
    lib/
    static/  <------- STATIC_ROOT - used in production. `collectstatic` collects here
    static_assets/ <- STATICFILES_DIRS - used in local dev
        css/
        less/
        js/
        images/
    templates/  <---- TEMPLATE_DIRS
    manage.py
```

settings.py is typically:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    . . .
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    . . .
)

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_assets'),
)
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
)
```

Then in templates, you can again use the staticfiles app's template tags to build out paths to static files:

```
{% load static from staticfiles %}

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/normalize.css' %}" />
```

Also note that with `<link>` tags, you need to use the `href` property for the url instead of `src`.

Comment: Thank you so much! The issue was in the HTML document the load static and href fixed the issue. I guess it is best to follow the docs verbatim!

Answer (score 0):

In your setting.py file add this

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

create a folder in your app named static and in your template file add this {% load static %}